# How to convert Bitmap Image to png in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I convert an Image stream or Bitmap image to png using Image tools in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using the ImageTools, it can be done like this:

```
ExtendedImage image = new ExtendedImage();
image.SetSource(imageStream);

ImageTools.IO.Png.PngEncoder enc = new PngEncoder();
enc.Encode(image, resultStream);
```

Where `imageStream` is the bitmap stream and `resultStream` is the PNG resulting stream.

Comment: what about  transparency?